# Minimizing ViewState size in ASP.Net, is there a difference between initializing control values in the constructor versus OnInit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, default-value

Ok I'm trying to understand how best to handle `ViewState`, for the programmatic setting of default values using C#. I understand that the construction of the `ViewState` hidden field is based on every value that is set after the `OnInit` event is triggered. What I'm not clear about is if there is a difference between using the control's constructor or the `OnInit` event to set default values.

```
public MyControl(){
    this.Text = "SomeDefaultValue";
}
```

versus

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e){
    this.Text = "SomeDefaultValue";
}
```

I've seen some places that suggest testing the ViewState value for `null` in the `get` of the given property, like so:

```
public string Text {
    get {
        return this.ViewState["Text"] == null ?
            "SomeDefaultValue" :
            this.ViewState["Text"] as string;
    }
    set { this.ViewState["Text"] = value; }
}
```

I don't like that because it makes clearing the value confusing.

So, Is there any functional difference between using the constructor vs `OnInit` to set default `ViewState` values?

Comment: If nothing else, horrid scoping confuses things. Not a fan of K&R brace-lining at all.

Comment: on a side note you can use the '??' operator instead of ternary operator.  (string)ViewState["Text"} ?? "SomeDefaultValue";

Comment: Or, use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Comment: @Kyle True, same problem though

Comment: @David Then you can never clear the field lol

Comment: @Josh Russo, yea, I was just saying on a side note. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of minimizing ViewState, there is no difference, as ViewState starts tracking after the `OnInit` method is run.

There *are* some functional differences, however: until the control is initialized, you cannot access other properties like the `Page`. For this reason, I usually prefer to use either `OnInit` or some handler tied to the `Init` event.

Also, be careful about overriding OnInit: you should call `base.OnInit()` to make sure that other event handlers for the Init event still get called.

I highly recommend that you read this excellent article on the topic: http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx

#### Edit

To clarify, the ViewState starts tracking *for a given control* after the `OnInit` method is run *for that control*. So **in the given example, you are safe to override `OnInit`** like this:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e){
    this.Text = "SomeDefaultValue"; // Make sure this happens before base.OnInit
    base.OnInit();
}
```

This works because the `Text` property is saving the value to the ViewState *of this control*. However, let's say you have another child control (I'll use a `Label` as an example). That Label's `OnInit` will already have been run by the time your control's `OnInit` method is called. So if you want to change the Label's Text value, you'll need to do it during that label's OnInit phase (or sooner).

You could do it in the constructor of the current control:

```
public MyControl(){
    this.Label.Text = "SomeDefaultValue";
}
```

... but as mentioned earlier you won't have access to the external control structure, which may be necessary in some cases. A good alternative in these cases is to use an `Init` event handler on the label itself. You can hook up the event handler itself in your constructor:

```
public MyControl(){
    this.Label.Init += 
        (sender, e) => this.Label.Text = 
             ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("SomeControl")).Text;
}
```

... but this will only work if the control is declared directly as a member of your class. If the label is inside a template (like in a Repeater), you'll need to use markup to hook it up:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" OnInit="Label_Init" />
```

with the code-behind:

```
public void Label_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var label = (Label)sender;
    label.Text = ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("SomeControl")).Text;
}
```

This latter example has the advantage of working in just about every circumstance I can think of, but it requires more boilerplate code, as well as a change in markup. So pick your poison based on your specific situation.

Comment: Ok so I hadn't read far enough: 'You can override OnInit and do it there instead, but that suffers from the same problem. Remember when we learned how ASP.NET calls TrackViewState() during the OnInit phase? It does this recursively on the entire control tree, but it does it from the BOTTOM of the tree UP! In other words, as a control or webform, the OnInit phase of your child controls occurs BEFORE your own. A control will begin tracking ViewState changes in this phase, which means by the time your own OnInit phase begins, your child controls ViewState are all already tracking'

Comment: The constructor it is then. I don't usually need the Page property when setting defaults anyway.

Comment: @Josh Russo: See my edit. The OnInit method would work for the situation you cite, but not under all circumstances.

Comment: gotcha, good edit. I was wondering about the placement of the `base.OnInit()` (oh and I do use it, I just wrote my initial example too quickly)

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a detailed document on the ViewState [over at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx):

> ...server controls don't begin tracking
>   view state changes until right at the
>   end of the initialization stage.
>   Second, when adding dynamic controls
>   that need to utilize view state, these
>   controls will need to be added during
>   the Page's Init event as opposed to
>   the Load event.

Just from this alone, I would say, if you're utilising the ViewState, use `OnInit`.

Comment: That actually brings up a different question. If it's better in terms of `ViewState` size to add controls in the Page's `Init` event, why is the `CreateChildControls` method called so late? Should it be a good practice to call `EnsureChildControls()` within the `Init` event?

Comment: I can't address the sizing query (I can't see how one would expect it to differ, other than a theory of using it earlier meaning things aren't persisted, which won't happen and you wouldn't want it to anyway) but I would definitely say call `EnsureChildControls`, performance isn't an issue as if they are already created this method only checks a boolean value, and if not, well they certainly need to be.

Comment: You do have to be careful if you call EnsureChildControls() in OnInit. You cannot then have logic in CreateChildControls that is dependent on the current ViewState values.

Comment: Then when creating controls in `CreateChildControls`, why not handle the default view-state at such an instant? I don't know if I'm lost with regards to what you're trying to achieve. The only way, AFAIK, to 'minify' the view-state is to put less in it.

Comment: Putting less in ViewState is exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm just trying to wrap my head around the best practice for progammatically setting default ViewState values; regardless of if the are properties that directly set ViewState in a custom control, or if they are default values on controls used within a composite control.

Comment: Actually more accurately, putting less in the ViewState hidden field is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok, so I found the answer to this by reading the rest of [Truly Understanding ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) ... as long as you set the properties of the controls before adding them to the control tree, it doesn't matter when CreateChildControls is triggered. The values will be treated as default ViewState values. All changes made to control properties after adding will grow the ViewState hidden field.

Comment: Right. So you're sorted? Excellent. StriplingWarrior did a great job.